# Cannot access Apache in docker on EC2 on port 80 using a browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm new to docker, and I'm trying to run an instance on AWS using EC2.

I ran the following command:

```
sudo docker run -dit -p 80:80  httpd:2.4
```

With `docker ps` I have the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND              CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
04f62e26594e   httpd:2.4   "httpd-foreground"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   kind_cray
```

The security group is configured as below:

[image: EC2 security group]

However when trying to access the instance through the browser using the address `https://ec2-a-b-c-d.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com` I get the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

What could be happening?

Comment: You shouldn't share sensitive info such as your machines public address.

Comment: Before submitting this post, I removed the instance.

Answer (score 4):

> https://ec2-15-229-1-156.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com I get the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

You get error because you are using **HTTPS**. You have to use only HTTP, as by default ec2 instances do not support https.

Comment: In fact, I didn't even notice it. That really was the cause of it all. Thanks